# Npm and Nexus Repository Manager 3.1: fail to publish npm libraries on the repo

Tags: npm, nexus

I am trying to upload npm libraries on a Nexus Repository Manager 3.1. which is on a server. This server does not have internet access.

So, I did a npm install on another computer in order to have the needed libraries for npm. After that, I tried to publish them on the Nexus Repository Manager by doing: **npm publish “lib” – registry “repo adress”**.

It didn't work for 41 libraries: *acorn, bluebird, clean-css, colormin, cssnano, csso, ent, event-stream, form-data, glob, gulp, is-extglob, kind-of, parse-glob, postcss-colormin, postcss-convert-values, postcss-discard-comments, postcss-discard-duplicates, postcss-discard-empty, postcss-discard-unused, postcss-filter-plugins, postcss-merge-idents, postcss-merge-longhand, postcss-merge-rules, postcss-minify-gradients, postcss-minify-params, postcss-minify-selectors, postcss-normalize-url, postcss-ordered-values, postcss-reduce-idents, postcss-reduce-initial, postcss-reduce-transforms, postcss-selector-parser, postcss-svgo, postcss-unique-selectors, q, spdx-expression-parse, useragent, void-elements, xml-char-classes, xmlbuilde*r.

Sometimes the errors are that librairies are missing. For instance when I try to publish the **q** library, the error was that grunt was missing. Therefore, I published it on the repo but I still have errors which are:

1. Failed to exec prepublish script
2. verbose stack Error: q@1.4.1 prepublish: `grunt`

Moreover, when I try to install the **acorn** library the problem was that a library was missing. When I published the missing library on the repo, another library was missing and again and again.

How do i do to publish all the libraries on the repo ?

I have the 3.10.9 version of npm.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the answer is because all of those packages have dependancies.  So the errors you are getting are with the related dependancies.  You could probably push the packages by removing the dependancies from the package.json however, when you went to use these packages they wouldn't work because they don't have the dependancies.
Thus, I don't think there's any viable workaround here.  I believe the issue is because you're not on the internet and has nothing to do with Nexus.